# Android: Bringing activity to front at end of timer and resume app

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, mobile, timer

I found similar questions, but I can't seem to make any solution work for my scenario. I am new to development, so please bear with me.

In one of the activities in my app, there is a timer. I would like the following:

1) To have the timer continue to run in background even if user switches to other apps OR another screen within the app

2) To have only one such instance running from the app

3) Once the timer finishes, the app screen is back on top (similar to timer in the android stock clock app)

Comment: instead show the pending intent notifications to the users to open your app

Comment: That will not continue to run the timer though